Sum up the total on one column based on another column
I have a test table which as 2 columns item and ranking sorted by ranking desc
The test table looks like this

I would like to sum the item column of all the rows that have ranking smaller or equal to the current row ranking
With the example above, the result I would like to get is

Is there a way to achieve the result I wanted using just 1 sql statement without using stored procedure or temporary table?
I tried
select sum(item),ranking
from test
group by ranking

But that one only sum the row with the same ranking and not the ones with lower ranking.
Please help
Below is the script to quickly create the Test table along with its values for your convenience
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [item] [int] NULL,
    [ranking] [int] NULL
) 

GO


insert into test(item,ranking) values (1,1)
insert into test(item,ranking) values (3,2)
insert into test(item,ranking) values (1,2)
insert into test(item,ranking) values (5,3)

Thanks!

Please don't use images, the editor supports full table markdown

select sum(sum(item)) over(order by ranking ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),ranking
from test
group by ranking

Might do the trick.
The inner SUM does the pre-aggregation.
The outer SUM is a window function which does a running total based on ranking column. over(order by ranking defines the order of the accumulation, the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is frame of the accumulation, this means, we want to get all rows before in ORDER BY order including our row.

Thanks! That would resolve my issue but I have simplified my problem. If I add another column called category and each category have ranking on its own and I would like to confine the count within the category, how would you change the sql statement? I would expand my question to illustrate my concerns

@user1205746 if you oversimplifed your problem, and this answer answers the question as asked, then you should accept this answer and post a new question. And in future ensure your question covers your complete requirements to avoid wasting peoples time.

You can use OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY ...) as well as add category to the GROUP BY and it's smooth sailing. The PARTITION BY is the GROUP BY of window functions

Hah.. got it! Thank you @siggemannen, I appreciate your assistance! The option using rows between unbounded pretty slick and new to me

@user1205746 Note that ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW can be written shorter ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.
